# How to connect to OPEN workbook in another instance of Excel at ANOTHER PC

Tags: vba, excel

In the link below there is code which connects perfectly from a workbook in one instance of Excel to an OPEN workbook in another separate instance* of excel.

[How to connect to OPEN workbook in another instance of Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140256/how-to-connect-to-open-workbook-in-another-instance-of-excel)

The code I use from the link above is the Sub GetDataFromExternalXLInstance().

Although this code works only if the separate instance of Excel runs on the same PC.

Is there also a method to connect from a workbook in one instance of Excel to an OPEN workbook in another separate instance* of excel on ANOTHER PC within the same LAN?

Thanks!

*) you can run a separate instance of Excel by : Windows key > Run > type: Excel /x on commmand line and press Enter.

Comment: Have you tried mapping a drive to the other PC (which would have to have sharing turned on and that particular drive\directory shared). I'm not sure if you can access an already "open" workbook over the network. You can open one though.

Comment: Thanks, yes i can map to the other pc and reach the contents of a saved file. Although i can't connect to an open file. If i connect to a particular file i only receive the content as in the saved file and not the changed values as in the open file.

Comment: I found this post on this board. Maybe this will help. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150619/how-to-get-data-from-an-already-opened-excel-workbook-with-a-word-macro)

Comment: Thanks Mitch, although this is similar to link above with GetObject command to a file on the same PC.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Can I know if you found any solution? Thx a lot @user2165379

Comment: @ MRVMV Unfortunately I did never find a solution for this problem.